# Auto-Increment id in java

Tags: java

Team one and Team two have both id 0? What am I doing wrong? I'm just trying to auto increment the id every time a new object is made.

This is code from **Team.java**

```
public class Team{
    private int teamId;

    public Team(){
        this.teamId= teamId++;
    }
    public void printTeamId(){
        System.out.println(this.teamId);
    }
}
```

This is code from **Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Team one= new Team();
    Team two= new Team();
        one.printTeamId();
        two.printTeamId();
    }
}
```

Comment: `teamId` is not shared by both Objects. declare is as __static__ `private static int teamId;`.

Comment: Static means that it's shared by both objects? As in it's not tied to any object? I got it working now Thank you!

Comment: teamId is 0 inside every new Team object you make. When you create a new Team object, the object has no idea what the other Team objects teamId values are set to since the variable is private and outside of the current scope.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need an extra static variable to store the amount of teams. `static` means that all the objects share this variable. Every team has it's own variable `teamId`, but share the variable `teamIdCounter`

```
public class Team{
    private int teamId;
    private static int teamIdCounter = 0;

    public Team(){
        this.teamId= teamIdCounter++;
    }
    public void printTeamId(){
        System.out.println(this.teamId);
    }
}
```

If you are using multiple threads, check the other answers on how to use AtomicInteger to count your objects threads-safe.

Answer (score 6):

About the static variable is ok but if you want to be thread safe use Atomic Integer.

```
public class Team{
    private int teamId;
    private static AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Team(){
        this.teamId= atomicInteger.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public void printTeamId(){
        System.out.println(this.teamId);
    }
}
```

This will make a thread safe counter instead a static counter that will not be thread safe.

Answer (score -2):

Make your teamId variable static & initialize it with some integer value (recommended is -1).

Using initial value -1 cause first teamId = 0.

Comment: This approach isn't thread safe. If two concurrent threads instantiate Team objects, more than one team could get the same ID. For thread safe counters, either use AtomicInteger or else synchronize updates.